# Html syntax not recognized inside If condition of Razor MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Below is the code i am using for one of my mvc views, within the mentioned if condition, html code is not recognized.

```
<table class="table">
        <tr class="row h4">
            <td>Task</td>
            <td>Parameter</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Mapping" /></td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (OrderTypeTaskParameterMapping mapping in Model.OrderTypeTaskParameterMappings)
        {
            <tr class="row">
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        @foreach (Task task in Model.Tasks)
                        {
                            <option value="@task.Id"
                                    @if (mapping.TaskId == task.Id)
                                    {
                                        selected="selected" **doesn't work**
                                    }
                                    >@task.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        @foreach (Parameter p in Model.Parameters)
                        {
                            <option>@p.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (mapping.Active)
                    {
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Active" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="InActive" />
                    }
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

On executing the above code i get an error :
[image]

What could be the reason? I thought this should have worked. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Use the strongly typed `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper so your html is constructed correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the work around. Could you still point out the issue in the original code.

Comment: Downvoter, can you please let me know the reason? Isn't this as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569710/793784

Comment: It will work if you use `@:selected="selected"` or `<text>selected="selected"</text>` And using the html helpers is not a 'workaround'! its the correct way. you code is truly awful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it also works using conditional attributes:

```
<option value="@task.Id" selected="@(mapping.TaskId == task.Id)">
```

If the expression evaluates to `false`, then Razor will not output the `selected` attribute.

[More on conditional attributes](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/conditional-attributes-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp.net-mvc-4)

About the original question, I believe the problem is related to how Razor tells HTML from C# blocks. On your code, you are not closing the `option` tag. You're trying to open it, write (or not) the `selected` attribute using a code block and then close it.

Inside the code block, Razor's expecting a line of code or a new HTML tag. As it's not an HTML tag (no angle bracket) it tries to interpret it as C#, hence the `missing ;` message.

That's why the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags inside the parent `@foreach(){}}` are working: because they can be interpreted as new HTML blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i got multiple answers to this question and now i am trying to find out what is wrong with the original code.

Comment: Updated the answer with more information about what I think is wrong on the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<option value="@task.Id" @(mapping.TaskId == task.Id ? "selected" : string.Empty)>
```

Inside {} you can use only C# code

Comment: Is it? What about the whole bunch of <tr> <td> tags i am using inside the parent @foreach(){} . That surely works!

Comment: I tried your code, that looks like something i should have done. It works! Still i would like to know what wrong in the original code. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry Jacek, Answer by Anderson looks more relevant to me, so shifting the marked answer.