# how to add multiple attribute for DropDownList in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have database table `T_HD_FUNC` with 3 fields: `FUNC_ID`, `FUNC_NAME` and `SYS_ID`. In the controller I have some code below:

```
ViewBag.FUNC_ID = new SelectList(db.T_HD_FUNC.OrderBy(d => d.SORT), "FUNC_ID", "FUNC_NAME", "SYS_ID");
```

Inside the view I have some code below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FUNC_ID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Area_ID, "Select menu", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The result: display value and Name like this image below

[image]

But sometime, We want display to display more than one field attribute. In this case I want display attribute `filterid` for column `SYS_ID` like this.

```
<option value="1" filterid = "1">Style master</option>
<option value="2" filterid = "2">Styles Development</option>
<option value="7" filterid = "1">Style Listing Gallery</option>
```

How can I achieve like this?
Thanks

Comment: You cant - the `DropDownList()` method only generates a value attribute and the text based oneach `SelectListItem` (and that's invalid html anyway). Explain why you want  to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add attribute to select list option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285303/add-attribute-to-select-list-option)

Answer (score 0):

using this:

$('yourElement').attr("yourAttribute", yourValue)